# Sybase ASE Performance Difference Between a JOIN and "IN"

Tags: sql, inner-join, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

Is there a performance difference between the ways of querying two tables in Sybase ASE, if there are 10 million records in each table:

```
    select top 1000 a.* from tableA a, tableB b
    where a.id = b.id
```

```
    select top 1000 * from tableA 
    where id in (select id from tableB)
```

Assuming that both tables have unique and non-null values for id.
Intuitively: the first is faster than the second one.

Comment: Test it and find out.  I imagine the answer is "yes", though.

Comment: If tables a & b are indexed with clustered indexes, with these sizes, it should be faster than creating a temp object in (select distinct id) statement.